# Why is JavaScript not working in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm coding the simplest Chrome extension using HTML and JavaScript, but apparently JavaScript is not working, and I don't know why. Here is the my HTML code:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
  </script>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box">
```

and here is my manifest.json file code :

```
{
  "name": "Blank new tab page",
  "version": "0.2",
  "incognito": "split",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "blank.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Inline JS is not allowed in popup pages. And IMHO it is a good thing, not only for security as Chrome claims, but also forces people to separate structure from behavior.

Comment: The duplicate question has an answer that will solve the issue. Be sure to search first! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your HTML DOCTYPE transitional? If not, maybe your code should look more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<body>
  <input type='button' value='Show alert box' onclick='myFunction()' />
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction(){
      alert('I am an alert box!');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I rearranged it. Your code should work though. I personally would recommend that your code look more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<body>
  <input type='button' value='Show alert box' id='btn' />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    showAlert('btn');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`external.js` will be cached. It can look something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function showAlert(e){
  E(e).onclick = function(){
    alert('I am an alert box!');
  }
}
```

The latter code is more reusable, and will give you an idea about jQuery's `$()`. It's a way more sophisticated version of my `E()` function.